# Garage heater wiring

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, heater

[image]I am getting a garage heater(240v 30a) it is suggested that it is hardwired to the panel. I was wondering if I am able to use the dryer outlet that is in my garage it is rated the same(240v 30)(looking at the plug it says 250v but when i used the voltmeter it did show 240v). Am i able to use this plug instead of hardwiring into the fuse panel?

Comment: Is that dryer outlet 3-prong (NEMA 10), or 4-prong (NEMA 14)?  (If you can't tell, just post a photo here)

Comment: It is 3 prong nema 10 30r. Trying to find out how to add picture now.

Comment: In theory it should work, given appropriate cables and connectors. Whether it would meet code, I have no idea.

Comment: Do you still use the dryer there?  The one problem with using both on that plug is the dryer wants hot, hot, neutral and the heater(if three wires) wants hot, hot, and ground(NEMA 6-30).  A bare neutral and no dryer simple.

Comment: No the dryer is on its own plug in the basement.

Answer (score 1):

That is a NEMA 10-30, which has two hots (which you need) and neutral (which you don't need for a heater, but do need for a dryer) but does *not* have ground (which you need for anything except a direct dryer replacement, which is not your case here).

Open up the receptacle. There are four likely possibilities:

- Cable with black and white hot wires and uninsulated neutral. The neutral can be turned into ground. Easy.
- Cable with black and red hot wires, white neutral and bare ground. You have everything you need, including if you wanted to install a modern 4-wire dryer receptacle.
- Cable with black and red hot wires and white neutral wire. You can't use this without adding a separate ground or replacing the cable.
- Individual wires in conduit. If you have a bare or green wire then you are all set. If you don't then you can *add* a bare or green wire for ground.

However, in any case you can **NOT** use this receptacle. You actually don't want to anyway - far better to hardwire a heater and eliminate one point of failure. However, since this is an old ungrounded receptacle you can't use it anyway. The only advantage of using a plug/receptacle here instead of hardwiring is if you want to have the circuit *also* be used for EV charging. However, there are some complications with doing that - basically 30A receptacles are not always designed for frequent plugging/unplugging of cords. In addition, depending on NEC version adopted in your area, you may need to install GFCI protection, which is not cheap (special breaker) but which generally has an exception for *hardwired* EV charging. A receptacle (whether for a heater or EV charging) generally requires GFCI once your jurisdiction adopts the 2020 NEC, and even hardwired may require it as well, except for EV charging because that normally includes its own GFCI protection.

Comment: So if there is a bare ground in the receptacle is it possible or safe to use? Or would this cause problems? Is my best bet other than hardwiring it in to convert it to a 4prong?

Comment: Your best bet **for a heater** is hardwiring. Most dryers are generally not hardwired (in the US), so if you wanted to go back to a dryer in this location then you would convert to 4-prong. Yes, if there is a bare ground lurking (along with two insulated hots and one insulated neutral) that is safe to use as ground. The unusual (but possible) situation is a two insulated hots + *bare* neutral - and then you can convert the bare neutral to be ground.